# CORS issue while loading Catalyst App on Zoho CRM

Tags: cors, zoho, catalystbyzoho, catalystcloudscale

When attempting to load a Catalyst application as an iFrame within Zoho CRM, a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue arises. Despite my efforts to configure access control headers for the application, the changes aren't taking effect and the problem persists. How can this issue be resolved?[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the CORS problem, I would recommend adding the domain where your Catalyst application is being loaded to the "Authorized Domains" section within the Authentication feature's Whitelisting settings. You can locate the Authentication feature within the Catalyst Console under Cloudscale Service. For detailed guidance, you can refer to the help documentation available [here](https://docs.catalyst.zoho.com/en/cloud-scale/help/authentication/whitelisting/authorized-domains/introduction/).